# Correct nonsense sentence on "Established User" privilege page

Tags: bug, status-completed, help-center, grammar, privileges-page

The [Established User privilege page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) contains the following "sentence":

> An expanded usercard is only available if you have have at least 28 characters in their "About Me" section of their profile.

Can this be corrected so that it makes sense please?

*Edit*

I suggest:

> An expanded usercard is only available if the user has at least 28 characters in the "About Me" section of their profile.

Comment: Makes perfect sense to me. :P

Comment: I guess it would make more sense if it read: `An expanded usercard is only available if you have at least 28 characters in the "About Me" section of your profile.`

Comment: Hrrrmm seems like they just need to replace "you" with "they", and remove one of their extra "have"s. "An expanded usercard is only available if **they** <strike>you have</strike> have at least 28 characters in their "About Me" section of their profile."

Comment: @Rachel I'll go with that, although I would say "...in **the** "About Me" section..."

Comment: Hmmm, but there's a problem, @Rachel *which* extra "have" do they remove? </StupidFridayJoke>

Comment: The left one, @Andrew - what else?

Comment: @Oded I didn't even notice that her sample edit already indicated which one to delete! </Fail>

Comment: Upvoted for great grammatical justice!

Comment: The proofreader/pedant in me would also like the randomly capitalised "Website" and "Location" to be lower-case and full-stops to be either included or excluded in the list beneath that as well...

Comment: It looks like this was already fixed as of the shift to the current privilege help pages back in October 2013, so I've marked this as [status-completed] (even though this info's moved to the "create posts" privilege page now anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget that nonsense. Take on the sentence after that as well. Now we have prog rock:

> An expanded usercard is only available if there are at least 28 characters in the "About Me" section of your profile. When your profile is long enough to show an expanded usercard a drop shadow effect will be shown on your avatar.